# Cant use LIKE but need to find related records in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've got a table used for issue tracking (kind of like stackoverflow :) to log PC related issues) and for simplicity I'll narrow it down to a few fields, something like the following:

```
Site               Category          Issue
MI Office          Software          My MS word does not run macros.
CL Office          Hardware          PC memory needs to be upgraded
MX Office          Printer           Printer is out of memory.
MI Office          Software          Office product prompts for allowing macro to run
```

I want to find related issues when I am looking at for instance one issue.  I can't really use the `LIKE` operator as for instance if I do:

`SELECT...FROM...WHERE Issue LIKE '%My MS word does not run macros.%'`

Would only return the first record.  Do I have to figure out how to pull key words like "Macros" ?  How would I find related records so that my query for instance could return records 1 and 4.  Or return 2 and 3 together?

Comment: My usual approach would be to categorize your issues and index them. For instance add a field called issue_type defining a category, and index using that. If you don't categorize, you'll have to do text-search, which would probably be LIKE if you do the search in SQL.

Comment: It is categorized, please look at my table definition.

Comment: Sorry! I somehow missed that.. Well, then how about `SELECT ... FROM .. WHERE Category = "Hardware" AND ...` ?

Comment: Sounds like you want a Full text index?

Comment: @MortenJensen - No that wont work becasue the category might be different but the issue might be related.  I think its a bit more complex then that.

Comment: @RowlandShaw would a full text index scan parts of a string rather then LIKE operator?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do then. From your question I take it you want to `SELECT` rows with a certain category and then checking for common words in the `Issue`s? If that's not the case, could you please elaborate a bit more in the question :)?

Comment: @MortenJensen no I want to find related tickets based on the issue.  I think Full Text might help but I've never used it.  I have to research it.

Comment: @oJM86o let me rephrase my question: What determines correlation between ticket issues?

Comment: @MortenJensen the contents of a ticket.  If I have an issue that says `My email keeps sending me an undeliverable for an email address I know is incorrect` and I have another email that says `Outlook keeps warning that e-mail delivery has failed to these reciepents or groups` to me they are related...what query or how could I bring these two results back.

Comment: @oJM86o there are no standard ways to correlate natural language AFAIK. There's a whole research field called natural language processing that deals with stuff like that. I know this isn't concrete help, but I think you'd have to define how you would correlate your ticket issues first. Kent's answer suggests tagging for correlation.

Comment: Yep I have already implemented tagging, that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Well here are 3 ways to go about it..

**1. Best case:**
We have the users add 'tags' to each issue. This way users can search issues using tags and find related issues too. (Just like http://stackoverflow.com ;) )

This could be implemented creating two new tables:

- tag_metadata (tag#, name, description, ...)
- tag_issue_relationship(tag#, issue#)

> We could go a step further and add weight to each issue entry that will determine its position in the similar issue search/look-up ranking.

**2. Average case:**
We have more levels to sub-categories to help further classify the problem. Now thinking of change control, will your system support easily adding/removing/re-arranging the category hierarchy over time..?

**3. Worst case:**
Lets say, the users are very lazy and don't want to spend a few seconds tagging their issues :).. Then you would have to implement an indexing algorithm that picks up keywords (nouns) for the issue description and builds indexes to facilitate finding 'similar' issues. Now many-a-times we may have keywords in the description that may not be significant and would result in false positives.

---

**[Update]**

Basically the solution what you are looking for could be broken up into these modules:

1. Parser: Will extract significant keywords from the issue description. A custom dictionary list of keywords would be used as the lookup table.
2. Indexer: Would index these keywords to make it searchable. This involves maintaining forward and [reverse indices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28search_engine%29#Inverted_indices)!
3. Search: Would use the indexes to locate 'similar' issues.

There may be an existing commercial/open-source product that does this..

Comment: Right I've already implemented tagging that is not good enough for a general search of tickets.  A lot of tickets are not tagged properly - I know this is more of a maintenance issue but we dont have a large community who can merge tags and come up with re-tagging.  Think small shop...I am looking more for something mentioned in my comments in the question.  If I have an issue that says `My email keeps sending me an undeliverable for an email address I know is incorrect` and I have another email that says `Outlook keeps warning that e-mail delivery has failed to these reciepents` need both rec

Comment: I will upvote not because I have an exact solution but you definately went out of your way.

Comment: Well that's great that you have implemented tagging.. and as @Morten suggested in the comments, having a Full-text search would just over complicate your solution. The reason I feel even a full text search won't work as well as user's are at times terrible at explain the issue they are facing... and don't we know it! :D This would ultimately result in false positives as mentioned in #3 worst case. – Kent Pawar 13 mins ago

Comment: @oJM86o Hey glad I could help a bit .. :) Well I was stuck with a similar issue a while back.. Unfortunately this is where we got stuck. Do update this if you find a better way around it.